# Good practices for combining multiple projects in one Docker Swarm deployment?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, docker-swarm

We're developing an application which consists of three parts:

1. Backend (Java EE) (A)
2. Frontend (vuejs) (B)
3. Admin frontend (React) (C)

For each of the above applies as status quo:

- Maintained in its own Git repository
- Has its own `docker-compose.yml`
- Has its own `Jenkinsfile`

The `Jenkinsfile` for each component includes a "Deploy" stage which basically just runs the following command:

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml $stackName`.

This approach however doesn't feel "right". We're struggling with some questions like:

- How can we deploy the "complete application"? First guess was using a separate `docker-compose.yml` which contains services of A, B and C.
- But where would we keep this file? Definitely not in one of the Git repos as it doesn't belong there. A fourth repo?
- How could we start the deployment of this combined docker compose file if there are changes in one of the above repos for A, B, C?

We're aware that these question might be not quite specific but they show our confusion regarding this topic.

Do you have any good practices how to orchestrate these three service components?

Comment: With Kubernetes I made good experience with separate repo and each service will update the  Kubernetes file with the newest build version. Should work the same for compose. For production you could use pull requests to have a more manual workflow. There is a yoututbe video from Kelsey Hightower explaining this setup. And there are some example projects in his github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one way to do that is to make the 3 deployments separate pipelines, so then as the last step per application you would just call the particular deployment. For example for backend:

```
stage("deploy backend") {
    steps {
        build 'deploy backend'
    }
}
```

Then a separate pipeline to deploy all the apps just doing

```
stage("deploy all") {
    steps {
        build 'deploy backend'
        build 'deploy frontend'
        build 'deploy admin frontend'
    }
}
```

Open question would be where would you keep the `docker-compose.yml`?

I'm assuming that automatic deployment would be available just for your master, so I would keep it still in each project. You would also need additional Jenkins configuration file for deployment pipeline - meaning you would have a simple pipeline 'deploy backend' pointing to this new jenkins configuration file in master branch of 'backend'. But then it all depends on your gitflow.